# Excel: Removing Left of character in entire column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My Column B is filled with different strings of text. I would like to remove the beginning part of the string of each cell.I would like to remove the string up until the common "" that is in the string.

I know I can do it by using =REPLACE, =LEFT, =IF, =ISERROR and =FIND. But I am just butchering the syntax and don't exactly where to use which function.

If someone could just give a little guidance I would really appreciate it. I am not trying to look for a handout, I just am having a difficult time rapping my brain around what exactly each part of the function is doing. If I figure it out ill post my solution. Thanks in advance.

```
<div style = "clear: right;text-align:right; float:right;"><strong><a href="http://xyz">xyz</a></strong></div><br><br>ABC
```

I want to get rid of everything in the cell besides the 
ABC, All the cells have different values for xyz though, hopefully this explains it a little clearer

Comment: I think you didn't phrase your question like you thought you did. Can you explain the first bit more clearly please?

Comment: The first sentence in your question doesn't parse.  Not at all sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: So basically, you want to extract ABC from the string?

Comment: Basically, there was also 2 line breaks that I wouldn't mind keeping and I thought it would be easier to extract right of the ending div tag since there was only 1 of those, but yes basically.

Comment: Do you have any indication on how long the text is you want to capture: is it always 3 letters like ABC or can it vary?

Comment: `=REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("find_text",A1,1)+1,"replacement_text")`

Comment: ABC's length varies drastically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps

```
=mid(A1,search("</div>", A1)+6,len(A1))
```

Comment: I got it to work for some cells but not others I dont know why

Comment: Nvm, and thank you. I got it working and understand the +6 thanks again

Comment: I think you don't need the third argument of the function- `MID` will return the rest of the string by default.

Comment: not in a cell-the worksheet function doesn't work the same way as the vb function